# LikedList of Linked List JAVA

Tags: java, tree, linked-list

I have a tree with a adjacency list for every node and i would like to traverse all the tree from node labeled '1' using a memorization of path but I've some problem with my JAVA code:

```
private static LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>> ricorda = new LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>>();

static LinkedList<Integer> visitati = new LinkedList<Integer> ();

public void CreaRic(int numberNodes) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= numberNodes; i++) {
        LinkedList<Integer> k = new LinkedList<Integer> ();
        ricorda.add(k);
    }

    int start = 1;
    LinkedList<Integer> percorso = new LinkedList<Integer> ();
    percorso.add(start);
    visitati.add(start);
    ricorda.set(start, percorso);
}

public static void implementPathIter(int start) {
    Iterator<Vertex> ka = adjacentTo(String.valueOf(start)).iterator();
    while (ka.hasNext()) {
        Vertex an = ka.next();
        LinkedList<Integer> path = ricorda.get(start);
        path.add(Integer.parseInt(an.name));
        ricorda.set(Integer.parseInt(an.name), path);
        System.out.println(ricorda.toString());
        visitati.add(Integer.parseInt(an.name));
    }
}
```

this part is only for the node root and it's the first step. For example imagine that the tree has the node 1 that is adjacent to node 13 and 14, i want that the final result of LinkedList ricorda is:

```
[[], [1], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [1, 13], [1,14]]
```

but the result is

```
[[], [1,13,14], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [1, 13,14], [1,13,14]]
```

Why? (I suppose the problem is here `path.add(Integer.parseInt(an.name));`)

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: I don't see how this is a tree. Maybe a graph. But you just have LinkedLists.

Comment: private static HashMap<Vertex, TreeSet<Vertex>> myAdjList;private static HashMap<String, Vertex> myVertices; this is the instance that represent the graph

Comment: @cricket_007 maybe you don*t see, but a node with one or more followers builds a graph which can be a tree.